# Integration of a piecewise function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to integrate a product of two piecewise functions over (0,1). My code is as follows:

```
def gfunc1(x):
    if np.logical_and(x >= 0.5, x<=1):
        temp =(-1.0)*np.pi*np.cos(np.pi*x)+(x+0.5)*(np.pi**2)*np.sin(np.pi*x)
    else:
        temp = np.pi*np.cos(np.pi*x)+(1.5-x)*(np.pi**2)*np.sin(np.pi*x)
    return temp
def lfunc(x,*args):
    return args[0](x)*args[1](x,args[2])
def bfunc(x,i):
    if (i == 0):
        if np.logical_and(x <= dxl[1], x>= dxl[0]):
            temp = (dxl[1] - x)/(dxl[1]-dxl[0])
        else:
            temp = 0.0
    elif (i == (len(dxl)-1)):
        if np.logical_and(x >= dxl[len(dxl)-2], x <= dxl[len(dxl)-1]):
            temp = (x- dxl[len(dxl)-2])/(dxl[len(dxl)-1] - dxl[len(dxl)-2])
        else:
            temp = 0.0
    else:
        if np.logical_and(dxl[i-1]<=x,x<=dxl[i]):
            temp = (x - dxl[i-1])/(dxl[i]-dxl[i-1])
        elif np.logical_and(dxl[i]<=x,x<=dxl[i+1]):
            temp =(dxl[i+1]-x)/(dxl[i+1]-dxl[i])
        else:
            temp = 0.0
    return temp
dxl = np.linspace(0,1,100)
res = quadrature(lfunc,0,1,args=(gfunc1,bfunc,1))
print res[0]
```

I got Error message: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
Could someone help me to fix the bug? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you specify where abouts this error occurs?

Comment: The error occurs at the step quadrature(lfunc,0,1,args=(gfunc1,bfunc,1)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in the definition of piece-wise functions.

Try doing it this way:

```
def gfunc1(x):
    return np.where( ((x >= 0.5) & (x<=1)), 
        (-1.0)*np.pi*np.cos(np.pi*x)+(x+0.5)*(np.pi**2)*np.sin(np.pi*x),
         np.pi*np.cos(np.pi*x)+(1.5-x)*(np.pi**2)*np.sin(np.pi*x)  )
```

Note the use of `&` instead of `and` for logical vector arrays, 
and the use of `np.where` as a vectorized if-else substitute.

I haven't tried to fix your entire code, the other functions that need an if-else may need to be redefined this way as well.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you very much. Your code works. But I still don't understand the difference between np.where and logical vector arrays. Could you please give me some resource on that? I tried to find the difference on python.org. Unfortunately, I could not find the best explanation.

Comment: There's http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.html which I think is too complicated.  Unfortunately, numpy.org is in a parked/unpaid status at the moment.

Comment: `x` is a `numpy` `array` of `doubles`. A condition like `x>1` is not a single `True` or `False` but a `numpy` `array` of `boolean` values, one for each value of x.  if x>1 ` is problematic for Python because it is not one value... and that's what the error message you received was all about.  `np.where( boolean array, array to use if true, array to use if false)` returns an array that is the proper answer for each boolean in the boolean array and takes care of calculating it in a proper pythonic way. Note that it calculates both values for every case and uses the booleans to select/ merge.

Comment: Python's `and` expects the left and right sides of the `and` to be simple boolean conditions, not arrays.  If `x` is a `numpy` `array` of floating point double-precision values, `x>1` and `x<2` are boolean numpy arrays. `and` won't work because it expects single booleans on each side.  `&` is the "and" operator for arrays.

Comment: Thank you Paul for the explanation.